# Swift Generic enum function to check case

Tags: swift

Is it possible to create a Generic enum function that returns a boolean if an enum instance is an enum Type or does this already exist and I don't know about it?

---

I use a ton of enums in my projects. Very often I define enums with associated values.

Simple Example:

```
enum Mode {
    case new
    case edit(Record)    // Record is a struct type
}
```

I regularly check whether an enum instance is a specific enum case. Many times, however, I don't need to check the associated value. I'm looking for a convenient way to check the case. Each method I know about has a downside.

### Method 1-2: If Case pattern matching or Switch case

```
let myMode = Mode.edit
if case Mode.edit(_) = myMode {
    // do something
}

switch mode {
case .edit:
    // do something
default:
    break    
}
```

Downsides:

- Cannot assign the check to a variable directly. Must do so in closure
- cannot use this pattern directly as an argument to a function

### Method 3-5 Implement an enum function or check value of computed property or Equatable protocol

Downsides:

- must be implemented for each enum type

---

Instead, I'm looking for a way to write a Generic function that returns a boolean if a enum instance matches an enum case. Something that can be written once and be applied to all enums. Similar to Generic function for Struct and Class Types:

```
func checkType<T, S> (a: T, _: S.Type) -> Bool {

    return a is S   // though you could just call this directly
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a good idiomatic way of achieving this. The only thing that comes to mind is to compare the raw memory of your enum instance against a dummy instance with the desired case.

As we don't care about associated values we would only need to require their respective last byte to be identical.

```
func unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly<A>(_ lhs: A, _ rhs: A) -> Bool {
    var (lhs, rhs) = (lhs, rhs)

    let offset = MemoryLayout<A>.size - 1

    return withUnsafePointer(to: &lhs) { lhsPtr in
        withUnsafePointer(to: &rhs) { rhsPtr in
            let lhsPtr = unsafeBitCast(lhsPtr, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)
            let rhsPtr = unsafeBitCast(rhsPtr, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)

            return memcmp(lhsPtr.advanced(by: offset), rhsPtr.advanced(by: offset), 1) == 0
        }
    }
}
```

This is far from pretty, but it works.

```
enum Test {
    case a(Int)
    case b(Int)
}

let a1 = Test.a(1)
let a2 = Test.a(2)

let b1 = Test.b(1)
let b2 = Test.b(2)

unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a1, a1) // true
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a1, a2) // true
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a2, a2) // true

unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(b1, b1) // true
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(b1, b2) // true
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(b2, b2) // true

unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a1, b1) // false
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a1, b2) // false
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a2, b1) // false
unsafeEqualityLastByteOnly(a2, b2) // false
```

Use your own judgement to decide whether or not this is something you want in your project. It's obviously not a technique that should be recommended without any reservations.

Comment: First. Thanks for this answer. If nothing else, it confirms my suspicion that there isn't a perfect way to do this.    I, however, don't think I would use this in production code, when at the end of the day, I'm just avoiding implementing known, safe solutions, even if they are repetitive.   I'll let this sit for a few more days and hope for more answers. If this is the best we can do, then I'll mark correct, for the academic solution.